# Clase con varios wcf services referenciados

Tags: c#, poo, wcf

me gustaría saber si es posible lo siguiente:

Deseo crear una clase que referencie varios ws y que en la clase tenga las propiedades que en la mayoría de los services utilizan las mismas variables...

```
public class wsProcedimientos
{
 //********  Propiedades  *****************
    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    public string PwdService { get; set; }

    public FileStream ArchivoAid { get; set; }

    public string NumeroDocumento { get; set; }

  ///....etc
 //********  Metodos  *****************
    void wsReferenciado1()...
//*** Aca instanciar ws1 y realizar acciones

    void wsReferenciado2(string User, string pwdService)...
//*** Aca instanciar ws2 y realizar acciones

    void wsReferenciado3(string User, string pwdService, FileStream archivoAid )...
//*** Aca instanciar ws3 y realizar acciones

    void wsReferenciado4(string User, string pwdService, NumeroDocumento)...
//*** Aca instanciar ws4 y realizar acciones

 }
```

Al instanciar esta clase, el objeto debe tener el comportamiento que solo tome el service que voy a utilizar (según el caso) por ejemplo:

```
 wsProcedimientos wsP = new wsProcedimientos();
 var response = wsP.wsReferenciado2(strUsr, strPwd)
```

Como referencio varios ws es probable de que se haga una carga del ws que se requiera usar al momento de instanciar? soy nuevo con wcf

Comment: Te recomiendo que reformules tu pregunta, porque como esta redactada esta basada en opiniones, lo que no es bien recibido en StackOverflow

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal soy novato con wcf no se si se pueden referenciar varios ws y realizar lo que coloco en el ejemplo, eliminaré la ultima linea de la pregunta y redactarla mejor.

Comment: Me refiero donde hablas de buenas prácticas, si lo son o no, es y será siempre una opinión, ese tipo de temas los podes hablar en el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)

Comment: cada metodo de tu clase puede referenciar un servicio distinto sin problema alguno, en cada metodo creas una nueva instancia del servicio correspondiente, en el constructor de la clase podrias instanciarlos todos pero no tendria sentido la sobrecarga de procesamiento.

Comment: @nerdcoder la sobrecarga de procesamiento, es lo que no deseo no se si con inyection o algo parecido se pudiera hacer

Comment: En tal caso sólo deberías instanciar el servicio correspondiente en el método indicado y nunca en el contructor, adicionalmente si todos tus servicios que llamas reciben un user y pass esos deberías pasarlos al constructor para reducir los parámetros en los métodos.

Comment: Instanciar el servicio en cada método... eso ya lo hice... Lo que no entiendo es pasar los parametros (los que se utilizan en todos los metods) los envio al constructor?         public wsProcedimientos()
        {
            this.Usuario = _usrService;
            this.PwdService = _pdwService;
        } podrias colocar algo de codigo? para calificar tu respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolviste lo de las llamadas a los servicios, ahora te queda reestructurar tu código solamente. username y password pasan al constructor con una sobrecarga sin argumentos.

```
public class wsProcedimientos{
    public String userName;
    public String password;
    public wsProcedimientos(){};
    public wsProcedimientos(String userName, String password){
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public void wsReferenciado1(){}

    public void wsReferenciado3(FileStream archivoAid){}

    public void wsReferenciado4(int NumeroDocumento){
        new servicio(this.userName,this.password);
    }
}
```